# Why is Process.WorkingSet > Process.MaxWorkingSet?

Tags: .net, process, working-set

Idle curiosity...

I'm looking at some of the properties of the current process:

```
using(Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
{
    // Inspect properties
    // p.MaxWorkingSet = 1,413,120
    // p.MinWorkingSet = 204,800
    // p.WorkingSet = 54,140,928
    // p.WorkingSet64 = 54,140,928
}
```

From my reading of the documentation, these properties are all related to the working set size in bytes, hence I was expecting to see:

```
MinWorkingSet <= WorkingSet <= MaxWorkingSet
```

This is not the case, can anyone explain why?

Comment: It looks to me like MaxWorkingSet IS bigger. Look at the dot in WorkingSet.

Comment: @Brian, apologies, that period should be a comma, corrected.  I'd manually replaced my local thousands separator by a comma and missed that one.

Comment: No problem and +1 for a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MaxWorkingSet and MinWorkingSet are the values returned by the Win32 API [GetProcessWorkingSetSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683226.aspx). These are limits used by the virtual manager that will be enforced when the memory is in short supply. As long as enough memory is available, the current working set size is allowed to grow larger than the value in MaxWorkingSet.

Comment: Interesting. If you have a MSDN account it would be good if you could at this information.

Answer (score 1):

While the [MSDN is not really](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process.maxworkingset%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) [helpful in this case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), a small investigation with the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) on the other hand revealed that the values for `Private Memory`/`MaxWorkingSet` and `Shared Memory`/`WorkingSet` do nearly exactly match.

Which makes me *believe* (yes, I do lack hard evidence) that the `MaxWorkingSet` does display the private memory while the `WorkingSet64` does display the complete memory, including shared one.

<sub>I know what the MSDN says...and I don't care, I see something different in the Process Explorer.</sub>

Comment: About your last sentence: There are numerous examples - none of which I can recall right now - that shows that the MSDN indeed has errors. So, if you observe something that contradicts the MSDN, changes are high, that the MSDN has an error in it and not that your observation is wrong.

Comment: When I add the columns Min Working Set and Max Working Set in Process Explorer on a Windows 2008 R2, I see that all process except dwm.exe (Desktop Windows Manager has increased its values) have the same values 200Kb and 1300 Kb, that are also seen by Joe.